# Repeat mouse path with different start and end points

Tags: javascript

I have recorded mouse path stored as array.

```
record: function(selector) {
    var target = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.target = target;
    target.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        if (!event.isTrusted)
            return false;

        var x = event.pageX - target.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - target.offsetTop;

        this.addPoint(x, y);
    });
}
```

How can I repeat recorded path with other start and stop coordinates?
Could someone provide code example or library?

For example:

```
[0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4]
```

Start point is [0, 1] and end point [0, 4].
I want to repeat the same path but with different start and stop points.

Comment: If you want to be able to choose the start AND endpoint at the same, does that mean that you're okay with translating the path? Say the orig is [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4].  If you choose [0,-1] and [0,-7], then the path would be [0,-1] [0,-3] [0,-5] [0, -7] (stretched and goes in a different direction).

Comment: Create the path as deltas, not absolute positions. So if you started at [2, 0] then went up by 5 in y, you'd enter [0, 5] to mean you went up 5 in y. Similarly if you went up by 3 in y and down in x by 2, you'd have [-2, 3]. Given that each coord is now showing the difference between one point and  the next, you will find it easy to start at a point, then apply the deltas one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to "Could someone provide code example **or library**?", take a look at Paper.js (http://paperjs.org/features/#vector-geometry) and their tutorial on vector geometry (https://scriptographer.org/tutorials/geometry/vector-geometry).